# Segue Methods and Their Objectives

Tags: ios, swift

When I press the button, I want to initiate new view controller and I want to pass some information into new view controller. This is handled by without any segue methods by using global variables.

However, If I use segue method, Which one of them do I have to use ?

performSegue() or shouldPerformSegue()

Comment: Have you tried `prepare(for segue:sender:)`?

Comment: The first one, the second is a delegate method. Please read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistoryboardsegue

Comment: No I haven't ,but  I heard that we have to call one of these methods before preprare() method

Comment: prepare(for segue:sender:) method will notify the view controller that a segue is going to be performed. and when you call performSegue() method, it'll initiate the segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call

```
func performSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
           sender: Any?)
```

The above method will initiate your segue and you can push your next view controller.

For your info

```
func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, 
                 sender: Any?) -> Bool
```

The method will return Boolean value, that will specify if to perform segue or not. You have controller over it and you can allow segue to perform or not by return true/false from method.

**true** - Segue is allowed and will be performed

**false** - Segue is not allowed and will be aborted.

You can use this method if you want to override any segue you have defined in storyboard and want to perform any other at run time.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `performSegue` if you want to initiate a segue programmatically.

With `shouldPerformSegue` you can add additional logic to decide whether an initiated segue really should happen or not.

Finally in `prepareForSegue` you can - as the name suggests - prepare the segue (e.g. pass some data to the destination viewcontroller).